# Paste Error Excel to Powerpoint VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am pasting some excel data into powerpoint as a picture and I am having some issues. I have 290 files which I am pasting a table into slide 4, 5 and 6 of each PP file. This worked perfectly yesterday when I was only doing 1 table into slide 6. I have replicated the process and now I keep getting random errors at random times. Sometimes its file 10, others file 50, different everytime. The errors range from the paste datatype is not available OR the clipboard is empty. I have tried every datatype, pasting as a metafile, as a shape, as a picture, just basic pasting and nothing stops the error. I have no idea! Here is my code: PLEASE HELP !

```
Sub Update_Site_Report()

'Initiate Variables
Dim objPPT As Object
Dim PPTPrez As Object
Dim FinSlide As Object
Dim AssumSlide As Object
Dim RiskSlide As Object
Dim FinTable As Object
Dim AssumTable As Object
Dim RiskTable As Object
Dim fileNameString As String
Dim PicCount As Long
Dim PicCount1 As Long
Dim PicCount2 As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim fileN As String
Dim Directory As String


'Create and open powerpoint application

Set objPPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
objPPT.Visible = True

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Update site report table from spreadsheet

For i = 2 To 291
    Sheet20.Cells(18, 2) = Sheet20.Cells(5, i)
    Sheet20.Cells(19, 2) = Sheet20.Cells(6, i)
    Sheet20.Cells(20, 2) = Sheet20.Cells(7, i)
    Sheet20.Cells(21, 2) = Sheet20.Cells(8, i)
    Sheet20.Cells(18, 3) = Sheet20.Cells(10, i)
    Sheet20.Cells(19, 3) = Sheet20.Cells(11, i)
    Sheet20.Cells(20, 3) = Sheet20.Cells(12, i)
    Sheet20.Cells(21, 3) = Sheet20.Cells(13, i)

'Take column header from spreadsheet and set as filename

fileN = Sheet20.Cells(4, i)

' Allow directory to be set in excel tab

Directory = Sheet20.Cells(18, 5)


'Open powerpoint presentation at Directory with Filename

Set PPTPrez = objPPT.Presentations.Open(Directory & fileN & ".pptx")

'Set range for site report table

Set Financials = Sheet20.Range("A17:C21")
Set Assumptions = Sheet45.Range("A1:C7")
Set Risks = Sheet45.Range("A24:D41")

'Choose which slide to paste site report table

Set FinSlide = PPTPrez.Slides(6)
Set AssumSlide = PPTPrez.Slides(4)
Set RiskSlide = PPTPrez.Slides(5)

'If there is a table in powerpoint slide, delete the table

For PicCount1 = AssumSlide.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
    If AssumSlide.Shapes(PicCount1).Type = msoPicture Then
        AssumSlide.Shapes(PicCount1).Delete
    End If
Next

For PicCount = FinSlide.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
    If FinSlide.Shapes(PicCount).Type = msoPicture Then
        FinSlide.Shapes(PicCount).Delete
    End If
Next

For PicCount2 = RiskSlide.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
    If RiskSlide.Shapes(PicCount2).Type = msoPicture Then
        RiskSlide.Shapes(PicCount2).Delete
        Debug.Print
    End If
Next

'Paste the site report table into the site report

Financials.Copy
FinSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteShape
Set FinTable = FinSlide.Shapes(FinSlide.Shapes.Count)

Assumptions.Copy
AssumSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteShape
Set AssumTable = AssumSlide.Shapes(AssumSlide.Shapes.Count)

Risks.Copy
RiskSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteShape
Set RiskTable = RiskSlide.Shapes(RiskSlide.Shapes.Count)

'Set position of site report table in powerpoint

FinTable.Left = 36
FinTable.Top = 175
FinTable.Width = 614

AssumTable.Left = 36
AssumTable.Top = 80.8

RiskTable.Left = 36
RiskTable.Top = 80.8
RiskTable.Width = 641.5


'Set filename as string

fileNameString = Directory & fileN & ".pptx"

'Save file as filename

PPTPrez.SaveAs fileNameString

'Close powerpoint presentation

PPTPrez.Close

'Repeat for every site (column) - increment i

Next i

'quit powerpoint

objPPT.Quit

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox ("Update complete, click ok to exit powerpoint")

End Sub
```

Comment: My experience is that the Office Clipboard is a fragile thing. So I would always avoid using it. But you could try using [Application.CutCopyMode = False](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-cutcopymode-property-excel) after each paste to tell Excel that the last copied data was pasted. Also, since you are using late binding to PowerPoint, have a look whether [ppPasteShape](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/pppastedatatype-enumeration-powerpoint) really is what you think it is. Maybe it is simply a not defined `Variant` instead of 11.

Comment: I found the answer if you are curious. Somehow VB was pasting the image before the image made it onto the clipboard as a meta-file (i.e. datatype unavailable error). To fix it all I did was put DoEvents between copying and pasting and it fixed it easily.

Comment: Yes, as I said "Office Clipboard is a fragile thing". Glad if this "solves" it for you. For me it sounds like a bad workaround which will fail soon.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling Windows clipboard history solves this issue.